# How do I disable hover for a link ? I'm using li:hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I'm trying to disable the hover functionality for a menu.
I want it to be enabled only under certain conditions.
I've tried using `$(".ulColor").removeClass('hover');`, but that hasn't worked
The CSS code for enabling the hover is :

`li:hover ul, li.over ul { display: block; }`

Here is the HTML DIV inside which the menu resides -

```
<div id="pColorSelectorDiv" class="parentOfAll">  
    <ul id="colorNav" class="ulColor">  
        <li id="liColorNav" ><a id="colorSelected" class="firstAnchorChild">Colors</a>  
            <ul id="ulColorChild" class="ulColor">  
                <li><a id="bkgColor-1" class="bkgColor-1 anchorClass" name="colorPallete" onclick="colorPicked('1');">COLOR</a></li>  
                <li><a id="bkgColor-2" class="bkgColor-2 anchorClass" name="colorPallete" onclick="colorPicked('2');">COLOR</a></li>   
               <li><a id="bkgColor-3" class="bkgColor-3 anchorClass" name="colorPallete" onclick="colorPicked('3');">COLOR</a></li>   
           </ul>  
        </li>  
    </ul>  
</div>
```

Here is the rest of the CSS code :

```
div[id="pColorSelectorDiv"] ul {  
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 0;  
    list-style: none;  
    width: 50px; /* Width of Menu Items */  
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;  
    }  

div[id="pColorSelectorDiv"] ul li {  
    position: relative;  
    } 

.firstAnchorChild{  
    display: block;  
    text-decoration: none;  
    color: #777;  
    background: White; /* IE6 Bug */  
    padding: 5px;  
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /* IE6 Bug */  
    border-bottom: 0;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    }  


li ul {  
    position: absolute;  
    left: 49px; /* Set 1px less than menu width */  
    top: 0;  
    display: none;  
    background: White;  
    }  


/* Styles for Menu Items */  
.anchorClass{  
    display: block;  
    text-decoration: none;  
    color: #777;  
    background: White; /* IE6 Bug */  
    padding: 5px;  
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /* IE6 Bug */  
    border-bottom: 0;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    }  

.bkgColor-1 {background: #00FFFF; color: #00FFFF;}  
.bkgColor-2 {background: #0000FF; color: #0000FF;}  
.bkgColor-3 {background: #7FFF00; color: #7FFF00;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
li.hover:hover ul { display: block; }
```

instead of

```
li:hover ul, li.over ul { display: block; }
```

Now this style will affect `ul` only when `li` is hovered **and** has `hover` class.

[A simplified example](http://jsfiddle.net/6NxQ5/).

PS You might also benefit from using 'code sample' button on edit form (the one with zeroes and ones) to format your code. Among other things, it'll preserve indentation (and thus increase readability). The key combination is `ctrl+K`. I've edited one of your code samples to demonstrate it.

Comment: I added a button, clicking on which, the hover should be disabled. I execute this when the button is clicked $(".ulColor").removeClass('hover'); but it didn't work. Am I doing that incorrectly ?

Comment: Got it ! Sorry missed the point completely. Added the css line and then did this to enable the hover - $("#liColorNav").addClass('hover'); Which correctly adds the "hover" class. Thanks a bunch Nikita !!